# Elasticsearch analyze() not compatible with Spark in Python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, apache-spark, elasticsearch-py

I'm using the elasticsearch-py client within PySpark using Python 3 and I'm running into a problem using the analyze() function with ES in conjunction with an RDD. In particular, each record in my RDD is a string of text and I'm trying to analyze it to get out the token information, but I'm getting an error when trying to use it within a map function in Spark.

For example, this works perfectly fine:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
t = 'the quick brown fox'
es.indices.analyze(text=t)['tokens'][0]

{'end_offset': 3,
'position': 1,
'start_offset': 0,
'token': 'the',
'type': '<ALPHANUM>'}
```

However, when I try this:

```
trdd = sc.parallelize(['the quick brown fox'])
trdd.map(lambda x: es.indices.analyze(text=x)['tokens'][0]).collect()
```

I get a really really long error message related to pickling (Here's the end of it):

```
(self, obj)    109if'recursion'in.[0]:    110="""Could not pickle object as excessively deep recursion required."""--> 111                  picklePicklingErrormsg

  save_memoryviewself obj

: Could not pickle object as excessively deep recursion required.

raise.()    112    113def(,):PicklingError
```

I'm not sure what the error means. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to map the ES analyze function onto records of an RDD?

Edit: I'm also getting this behavior when applying other functions from elasticsearch-py as well (for example, es.termvector()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the `Elasticsearch` client is not serializable. So what you need to do is create an instance of the client for each partition, and process them:

`def get_tokens(part):
    es = Elasticsearch()
    yield [es.indices.analyze(text=x)['tokens'][0] for x in part]
rdd = sc.parallelize([['the quick brown fox'], ['brown quick dog']], numSlices=2)
rdd.mapPartitions(lambda p: get_tokens(p)).collect()`

Should give the following result:
`Out[17]:
[[{u'end_offset': 3,
   u'position': 1,
   u'start_offset': 0,
   u'token': u'the',
   u'type': u'<ALPHANUM>'}],
 [{u'end_offset': 5,
   u'position': 1,
   u'start_offset': 0,
   u'token': u'brown',
   u'type': u'<ALPHANUM>'}]]`

Note that for large data sets, this is going to be very inefficient as it involves a REST call to ES for each element in the dataset.